# A tool for test webpages in older Browsers?

Tags: asp.net, browsers, tools

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I see what my web site looks like in various browsers?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/21/how-can-i-see-what-my-web-site-looks-like-in-various-browsers)

Hi,

at the moment I develop a ASP.Net Page Community board.
I have installed FF4, IE9 and Opera 10.

A friend told me, my page looks bad in IE7 and maybe IE8.
Is there a tool how I can look the page for IE7/8, FF2/3 and maybe Opera 9?
You know, older versions of browsers without uninstalling my browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use IETester:

http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage

Also a couple of useful links thrown up in these questions:

[How can I test my site in IE6, IE7, IE8, IE9, IE10 and Internet Explorer 11](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/10865/i-want-to-test-my-web-site-on-ie6-ie7-ie8-and-ie9)

[How can I see what my web site looks like in various browsers?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/21/how-can-i-see-what-my-web-site-looks-like-in-various-browsers)